# Django lookup multiple models reusing querysets

Tags: django

Let's say I want to get a list of houses where the owner's car has a seat that's red.

I could do it like this:

```
queryset.filter(owner__cars__seats__color='red')
```

However, I would like to reuse the filter of getting cars that have a red seat, so I have a custom Queryset on Cars.

```
class CarsQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_red_seats(self):
         return self.filter(seats__color='red')
```

Is there a way to do reuse the "with_red_seats" filter on the first query?

Something like this, which obiously doesn't work:

```
queryset.filter(owner__cars__with_red_seats)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to reuse:

```
red_seated_cars = Cars.objects.with_red_seats()
House.objects.filter(owner__cars__in = red_seated_cars)
```

might do the trick

Comment: I would've preferred a more elegant solution, but this works.